# Approach to styling of Material artifacts, to harmonize with Legacy WebApp

Tags: web-applications, styling, legacy

We need to have  Angular-Material, styled so it harmonizes,  with a legacy web-Application.

How should one go about, to style a material component, e.g. mat-button.

Things as {Height, font-size, border-radius},  and similiar for hovering styles.

How does one find out which Style-classes or CSS-variables, need be tuned for e.g. a  mat-button.

Is such "Harmonization", at all supported ??

Creating new Pages with  Material,  gives styling  completely different,  from the Legacy-pages.

Kind regards
R. Tore

Looking for advice, how to best integrate Material into legacy App :-)